# Get external process ID by name

Tags: rust, process, pid

How can I get the process ID of another process by name?

I'm on windows 11. I know that `std::process:id` gets the PID of the application.

Comment: Please try [get_process_by_name](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.6/sysinfo/trait.SystemExt.html#tymethod.get_process_by_name) of the [sysinfo](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.6/sysinfo/index.html) crate.

Comment: Does this also work on MacOs?

Comment: Yes, I verified it works on my MacOS. Please note it returns a list of processes starting with the given name. pid is one of the fields of the [Process](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.6/sysinfo/struct.Process.html) struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [get_process_by_name](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.6/sysinfo/trait.SystemExt.html#tymethod.get_process_by_name) function of the [sysinfo](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.6/sysinfo/index.html) crate can be used to get the processes starting with a given name. pid is one of the fields of [Process](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.3.6/sysinfo/struct.Process.html).

```
use sysinfo::SystemExt;

fn main() {
    let mut system = sysinfo::System::new();
    system.refresh_all();

    for p in system.get_process_by_name("docker") {
        println!("{}:{}", p.pid, p.name);
    }
}
```

Using the `get_process_list` function is another option.

```
let ps = system.get_process_list().iter().filter(|(_, p)| p.name.starts_with("docker"));

for (pid, p) in ps {
    println!("{}:{}", pid, p.name);
}
```

Comment: In the 0.30.7 version, seems it's changed to https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.30.7/sysinfo/struct.System.html#method.processes_by_name